# how to dynamically resize container to fit <div>

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to dynamically resize the container based on the `<div>` panel displayed inside it. Currently,there are 4 `<div>` panels inside the container which fits the whole container fine. But the issues arises when there is only 2 `<div>` panels inside the container, then there will be plenty of space in the right side which I do not want. The container should resize based on the  panel inside it.

I have pasted the image how it looks currently.

When here are 4 panels:

[image: 1st]

When there are 2 panels

[image: 2nd]

So you can see that there are plenty of space in the right side. I want to auto resize the container to fit.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div>
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="ATab">
                <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Select">Select</a></li>
                <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Criteria">Criteria</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="Select" class=" tab-pane fade in active"></div>
                <div id="Criteria" class="tab-pane fade"></div>

                      <div class="container active col-md-3 col-sm-6 ">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">First Name</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container active col-md-3 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">Last Name</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Is this bootstrap? If so, you need to add it as a tag and remove the CSS3 tag.

Comment: @Rob, yes this bootstrap. Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: No. I would never use bootstrap

Comment: @Rob, how would you do this using CSS3.

Comment: That's too broad of a question and this will be closed for the same reason eventually. On Stack Overflow, you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** within the question itself

Comment: @Rob, I do not understand why are you saying that it is broad question. I have mentioned my scenario. I am trying it since last 2 days but not getting any solutions so posted here for help. If anyone has come across similar situation then they can help me. I have googled it and tried all possible solutions which i found here but no luck so far.

Comment: To ask me to show you how to write the CSS would make it too broad. Your original question does not seem to say, "This code should work but it doesn't so what is wrong with it?" but instead asks us to write it for you which, again, makes it too broad.

Comment: @Raj refer to the [Bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com)... "Rows are wrappers for columns... content must be placed within columns and only columns may be immediate children of rows"

Comment: @Rob, I am not asking you to write CSS for me. Just I asked how would you do if you come across similar situation. I know how to write CSS. I do not have any idea how to do this so not posted possible solution.

Comment: Then Stack Overflow is not the right platform for you.

Comment: @Rob, I think it is better to stop this discussion now. I know which i platform is right for  me so you should not tell me. Thank you!

Comment: @ZimSystem, Can you please provide sample solution. It would be great help. I am struggling since 2 days so posted here for help.

Comment: @Raj - Garrito has explained several good options for you to try, and answers your question. Now, *you* need to make an effort, and read the Bootstrap docs. There are various issues with the code, not only the `row`>`col*` issue, but also you shouldn't have nested containers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your containers have both `col-md-3` and `col-sm-6` classes so depending on your container width, they'll either take up 1/4 or 1/2 of the row. Your row with 2 panels will scale as you desire once the container width is <750px because the `col-sm-6` class will be active.
http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/css/#grid

This is a limitation with Bootstrap 3 and is updated in Bootstrap 4 where you could simply label them with `col` classes and it will automatically fit within the container width.
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#equal-width

If you don't want to/can't implement Bootstrap 4, then you could do a hybrid approach by removing Bootstrap classes in the wrappers for your panels and creating your own classes using Flexbox CSS3 properties. For example:

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">First Name</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Last Name</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then in your CSS:

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1;
  margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
}
```

The downside of this approach is you'll have to integrate media queries to handle what happens when the container width changes, etc. But hopefully this helps.

The last option (which I consider the least desirable) is a JS solution where `col-xx-3` and `col-xx-6` classes are toggled on your panel wrappers based on whether there are two or four of them but I really wouldn't recommend that.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/#flexbox-background

Comment: Thank you for your time. As I mentioned in my question. I want to resize the container based on `<div>` inside it. If there is 1 `<div>` then it does not look nice inside the container. I have very data to display inside single `<div>`. So if i can reduce the container size then it would be great. please help me.

Comment: I understand, but this kind of contradicts the nature of containers in Bootstrap. The container either has a fixed width or a full width if container-fluid is used so changing the width of the container based on the active tab and number of divs inside is a bit strange for Bootstrap thus why I suggest reading into Flexbox properties instead.

Comment: @user8827003, If you feel that this question is useful to other future readers on this site then can you please up vote this. Thank you!